# ABAP Memory ID or PARAMETER values in debugger

Tags: abap

Some of the ABAP programs that I have to debug use system memory to pass data to other programs using the following syntax:

```
EXPORT: VARIABLE_NAME  TO MEMORY ID 'NAME_OF_MEMORY_OBJECT'.
```

How do I check the value of these memory IDs in the debugger?

Relatedly, how can I view the value of parameter set with:

```
SET PARAMETER 'ZPR' FIELD lv_project.
```

Comment: As a tip, use a constant for the memory ID name, in this way you can check where it is used...

Comment: I usually don't use `EXPORT` myself, it's mainly in standard code, but that's a good point for development.

Comment: It is indeed a bad practice, but in some rare cases you can't have control over the code execution and you need to use it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Memory IDs

These memory IDs can be accessed in the debugger, but the option isn't accessible by default in the "new" Debugger. To display them you have two options:

- In the new Debugger, change one of the tools you're using. Do this by clicking the "New Tool" or "Replace Tool" that you can see at the top of the vertical button column on the right of each subwindow. Open the Special Tools folder in the tree and select "System Areas (Internal Only)". In the second tab of this tool you can now see a list of areas. Double-click the `MEMORIES` ("*EXPORT/IMPORT memories*") area or manually enter it in the Area input field to open the list of active memory IDs. Click through on any one to see its hexadecimal value.
- In the menu bar, open Debugger and select "Switch to Classic Debugger". Once it opens, find the following in the menu bar: Goto, System Areas, ABAP Memory. The system areas will be displayed with the `MEMORIES` area selected by default.

## Parameters

If you want to view the PARAMETERs that were set instead of memory IDs, the procedure is almost exactly the same. However, instead of opening the `MEMORIES` system area, open the `SMEM` ("*SAP memory (SPA-GPA)*") area.